# IFRAME. Запретить вывод в консоль

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Как запретить странице, загруженной, в **iframe** выводить данные в консоль браузера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если iframe из этого же домена, делаем так:

```
console = new Object();
console.log = function(log) {
// описываем тут что должна делать функция log 
};
console.debug = console.log;
console.info = console.log;
console.warn = console.log;
console.error = console.log;
```

Если из другого, ситуация осложняется.
Подробно вопрос разобран здесь:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479343/trying-to-capture-console-log-message-from-youtube-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Создать в ней фейковый объект консоли, функции в котором не будут ничего делать. Это если она в том же домене. Если в другом - то никак.
И вообще, не люблю, когда с консолью что-то делают. Чем помешало-то?

Comment: Отлаживать неудобно.